# how to write junit test case for AccessTokenVerifier and JwtVerifiers in java

Tags: junit, jwt, access-token, bearer-token, okta-api

## **AccessTokenVerifier**

---

How to write juint test case for AccessTokenverifier. I have attached the screenshot , code and dependencies details. please help if anyone know this.

please review the screershot.
[Jwt token verifier source code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABpt4.png)

### **Source Code**

```
  log.info("JwtVerifier start building to verify the authToken");
            AccessTokenVerifier jwtVerifier = 
                    JwtVerifiers.accessTokenVerifierBuilder()
                    .setIssuer(oktaTokenUrlIssuer)
                    .setAudience(TOKEN_AUDIENCE)
                    .setConnectionTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                    .build();
            
            jwtVerifier.decode(authToken);
            log.info("JwtVerifier build and verified the authToken successfully");
```

---

**Reference Link :** [okta verifier](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/validate-access-tokens/java/main/)

## Dependencies

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.okta.jwt</groupId>
   <artifactId>okta-jwt-verifier</artifactId>
   <version>${okta-jwt.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.okta.jwt</groupId>
  <artifactId>okta-jwt-verifier-impl</artifactId>
  <version>${okta-jwt.version}</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

I got exception when try to write test case `com.okta.jwt.JwtVerificationException: Failed to parse token`

Below I have attached my test case.

please refer this screenshot : [My test case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYOo6.png) .

my goal is to write test case to cover 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class JwtVerifierTest {

    @Test
    public void testVerifierBuildAndVerification() {
        String authToken = "valid_auth_token";
        String oktaTokenUrlIssuer = "https://my-okta-instance.com";
        String TOKEN_AUDIENCE = "api://default";

        AccessTokenVerifier jwtVerifier =
                JwtVerifiers.accessTokenVerifierBuilder()
                        .setIssuer(oktaTokenUrlIssuer)
                        .setAudience(TOKEN_AUDIENCE)
                        .setConnectionTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                        .build();

        try {
            jwtVerifier.decode(authToken);
            assertTrue(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            fail("Verification failed");
        }
    }
}
```